# Online editor for word files and way to preview files using GWT

Tags: file, gwt, gxt, preview

I have two requirements in my GWT 2.4.0 + GXT 2.2.4 + Amazon project,

1. We store the word documents in our app only (each login can access only his docs). Now i want that user can edit own word document online like ZOHO writer does. How can i achieve this functionality in my app?
2. We also stores the images, text files, word files, PDF files and others too. I want to show preview of those files when user clicks on the file. something like, docs.com. How to achieve this too?

I just need guidance that how can i achieve this two requirements. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to actually read the document on the client, or will you transfer the file to the server and process it there?

Comment: File is already there on server i just need to fetch it from server and display it on client then make user to edit it online. After this changes on file needed to be stored back on server.

Comment: Are you planning to develop a browser-based word processor? On the server you can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html) to extract the information from the Word documents, and to put your edits back into the documents. I think this will be easier if you read and write the documents on the server, but it still seems like a lot of work! Good luck!

Comment: Indeed Andy, not that simple. But I'm pretty sure that @vbjain came prepared :-). This SO question may help you to an extent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915020/web-based-word-processor

Answer (score 0):

GWT has come up with Wrapper class of Code mirror library for XML
Editor check this this is for client side

```
public XMLEditorPanel(int height, int width, final String xmlToDisplay) {
        this.xmlToDisplay = xmlToDisplay;
        setHeaderVisible(false);
        setHeight(height);
        setWidth(width);

        config = new CodeMirrorConfiguration();
        config.setLineNumbers(true);
        config.setTextWrapping(false);
        config.setAutoMatchParens(false);

        editor = new CodeMirror(config);

        editor.addInitializeHandler(new InitializeHandler() {
            public void onInitialize(InitializeEvent event) {
                editor.setParser(CodeMirror.PARSER_XML);
                editor.setIndentUnit(2);
                editor.setFocus();
                if (xmlToDisplay != null && xmlToDisplay != "" && xmlToDisplay.length() > 0) {
                    editor.setValue(xmlToDisplay, false);
                } else {
                    editor.setValue(" ", false);
                }
                editor.reindent();
            }
        });

        editor.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
                XMLEditorPanel.this.xmlToDisplay = editor.getValue();
            }
        });

        add(editor);
    }
```